# With Python's boto, how can I get the contents of an encrypted file?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto

With an unencrypted file, I can do the following:

```
key = s3_bucket.get_key(path)
value_as_string = key.get_contents_as_string()
```

But if the file's encrypted, I need to change something about that. I can't figure out what from reading the docs. What do I change?

I know the master symmetric key, which is a string like 30 chars or so long.

Comment: So value_as_string contains a string representation of the encrypted file? Why can't you just decrypt the string after retrieving it from S3?

Answer (score 2):

At this time, no version of Boto supports client supplied keys in it's API. Instead, you could use the AWS SDK.

The general process is this:

> When downloading an object – The client first downloads the encrypted
>   object from Amazon S3 along with the metadata. Using the material
>   description in the metadata, the client first determines which master
>   key to use to decrypt the encrypted data key. Using that master key,
>   the client decrypts the data key and uses it to decrypt the object.
>   http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingClientSideEncryption.html

Here is an example, in Java, that shows creation of a key, upload of a file that gets encrypted with the client key, and retrieval of the file and decrypted with the client key:

```
KeyPairGenerator keyGenerator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
keyGenerator.initialize(1024, new SecureRandom());
KeyPair myKeyPair = keyGenerator.generateKeyPair();

// Construct an instance of AmazonS3EncryptionClient
AWSCredentials credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(myAccessKeyId, mySecretKey);
EncryptionMaterials encryptionMaterials = new EncryptionMaterials(myKeyPair);
AmazonS3EncryptionClient s3 = new AmazonS3EncryptionClient(credentials, encryptionMaterials);

// Then just use the S3 client as normal...
//
// When we use the putObject method, the data in the file or InputStream
// we specify is automatically encrypted on the fly as it's uploaded to Amazon S3.
s3.putObject(bucketName, key, myFile);

// When you use the getObject method, the data retrieved from Amazon S3
// is automatically decrypted on the fly.
S3Object downloadedObject = s3.getObject(bucketName, key);
```

Source used/adapted from here: http://aws.amazon.com/articles/2850096021478074

In Python, no AWS "supported" .e.g. Boto option exists. However, there does exist a wrapper library for Boto that provides the ability to encrypt/decrypt using a client side-key is this library: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/s3-encryption/0.1.0

Comment: You're correct I'm using boto, not boto3, but isn't boto3 the recommended  library? It looks like that's the Amazon recommended API https://aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-python/

Comment: Seems like your example relies on getObject being automatically decrypted on the fly... but that's in Java. Is this true for Python's boto3 as well?

Comment: Have edited the answer to state that no version of Boto supports client-side encryption. There does exist this utility (I have not used it) that wraps Boto, providing the ability to specifcy client-side keys. https://pypi.python.org/pypi/s3-encryption/0.1.0

Answer (score 0):

If this is a file that AWS encrypted for you (by your setting the flag in boto to turn encryption on) then you don't have to do anything extra. S3 transparently encrypts and decrypts the contents. They're encrypted inside of S3, but in the clear in your program. So the same code works either way.

Comment: It's not. Client side encrypted, and I know the key.

Comment: Did you write the code to encrypt it? If so, it should be easy to write the decryption code.

Comment: @CharlesEngelke he's referring to s3cmd's client-side encryption provided by s3-tools, so no, he can't just write the decryption code. 

Via http://s3tools.org/kb/showall3.htm#9:
"With Client-Side encryption, you add an extra layer of security by encrypting data locally BEFORE uploading the files to Amazon S3. Client-side encryption and server-side encryption can be combined and used together. In S3cmd, client-side encryption is applied by specifying the flag -e or --encrypt."